# Setting a symbolic value to a real number

Tags: sympy

I have this code in in Python with SymPy:

```py
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, Matrix
phi = symbols('phi')
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
N1 = sympy.cos(phi)
N2 = sympy.sin(phi)
N3 = -sympy.sin(phi)
N4 = sympy.cos(phi)
N1.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N2.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N3.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N4.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
x=4
y=2
UVG = Matrix(2, 1, [x, y])
T = Matrix(2, 2, [N1, N2, N3, N4])
UVL = T*UVG
print("hi")
```

In debug mode the substitution of x =4 and y = 2 do seem to be working however the subs function does not seem to work for phi which is not being updated to an actual numerical value. I can see the output in my debug window where the value of UVL is showing as:

```py
Matrix([[2*sin(phi) + 4*cos(phi)], [-4*sin(phi) + 2*cos(phi)]])
```

Is there a way for SymPy to get the value of phi to change to an actual floating point or decimal type number so that I can get my transformed x and y back out?

I tried:

```py
N1.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N2.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N3.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
N4.subs('phi', sympy.Float(0.785))
```

and

```py
N1.subs(phi, sympy.Float(0.785))
N2.subs(phi, sympy.Float(0.785))
N3.subs(phi, sympy.Float(0.785))
N4.subs(phi, sympy.Float(0.785))
```

and

```
phi = 0.785
```

none of which seem to work at all in terms of changing phi to a floating point or decimal value or similar type.

Comment: The `if __name__ == '__main__'` branch is unhelpful in your code examples. It serves no purpose in this context so better to leave it out.

Comment: OK. T = Matrix(2, 2, [N1, N2, N3, N4]).subs('phi',0.785)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy objects are mostly immutable so the result of `subs` is a *new* immutable object, not a change to the original object. Several forms of `subs` all work

[image]

But if you want to work with that new value of `N1` you have to store it to a new variable. Consider:

```py
>>> from sympy import Tuple
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> t = Tuple(2*x, 1/x)
>>> x.subs(x, 2)
2
>>> t  # unchanged, containing symbolic x
(2*x, 1/x)
>>> t.subs(x, 1)  # replace value of x (=symbol x) with 1 in t
(2, 1)
>>> x = x.subs(x,1)  # making x a value, no longer a symbol
>>> t.subs(x, 1)  # same as t.subs(1, 1) => no change
(2*x, 1/x)
>>> _ == t
True
```

The reason it "worked" with `x` and `y` is because you defined their values before you used them so you saw the numerical values that you assigned to them in the expression in which they were used.